# The set of real numbers whose product is rational is Borel in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A=\{(x,y)|xy\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ be a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that A is a Borel set, and find its Lebesgue measure $m_2(A)$.

This is an exercise of the chapter of Fubini and Tonelli's theorem, so I wonder if we consider $f(x,y)=xy$, and the integral $\int_A f(x,y)dm_2$, which may be somewhat helpful. But I can't go on from there as I don't know how to link this to the Borel quality of the set.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Hint: $f(x,y)=xy$ is Borel measurable, and so, the inverse image of a Borel set is also a Borel set. To show that $A$ has zero Lebesgue measure, realize the measure of $A$ as the double integral of the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ and then apply the Tonelli's Theorem to convert it to an iterated integral.

Comment: @SangchulLee thanks, that is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split A into $$A=\cup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\{(x,y)|xy=r\}$$ and we can see that $A$ is a countable collection of zero-measure closed sets. Closed sets are Borel sets so we can conclude that $A$ is a Borel set and $m_2(A)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $xy = r \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$.
Then we have $y = r x^{-1}$. So $y$ is some rational multiple of $x^{-1}$.
On the other hand, if $y$ is some rational multiple of $x^{-1}$, then $xy$ is rational as well. Therefore, $A$ is the countable union (indexed with $\mathbb{Q}$) of copies of $\mathbb{R}$ (which has Lebesgue measure $0$) in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I am not sure how to show that it is Borel, though.